# Writing Waveform data into CSV file in LabVIEW

Tags: csv, export-to-csv, labview, data-processing

I have a LabVIEW program which contains voltage, current and power data into the same waveform. I am planning to extract each of them one by one and putting into array. Currently, I have extracted only the voltage waveform and converted the data into a CSV file.

However, the problem is that the time stamp (dt) and the y value are in the same cell of the CSV file which requires to post process in excel to get tab delimited format. I would like to get the end result without post processing.

Can anyone help me to correct the code with delimitor?

[LabVIEW Program for single parameter writing into CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYEQK.png)

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5ffw.jpg)

Moreover, If I want to add two more data (Current and power), how can I append them into another two columns in the CSV file and synchronize with the relative time (dt)?

Comment: Here's an extension that supposedly adds commas between strings.  That should convert your fields into comma-separated values.  I haven't tried this.  https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/insert-commas-between-array-numbers-help/td-p/118324